# Python splitting SQL statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to group all the statements which has alias 'a' into a variable and other statements into a different varaible.

```
data = (a.wing_group = 'mid' and a.flight = 'lower' and (tag_id = '1234567' or tag_id = 'abcd') or a.land='0')

a_data = a.wing_group = 'mid' and a.flight = 'lower' or a.land='0'
b_data = tag_id = '1234567' or tag_id = 'abcd'
```

I tried splitting the values, but no luck.

In reality this is a huge statement. And I am breaking that down and grouping it.

I am trying to construct a query like the below SELECT statement.

**Query**

```
"SELECT * FROM vortex v where 
    EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM v.avail_block a where a.wing_group = 'mid' and a.flight = 'lower' or a.land='0') and 
    tag_id='1234567' or tag_id = 'abcd'"
```

I tried spliting, but I can't get the operators put in the right place.

Comment: Your question makes no sense and doesn't appear to have anything to do with Python. You probably need to reword your question to include more context.

Comment: @KurtisRader, I have modified my question.